# How can I import both the Task Start date and the Task Finish date from Excel at the same time, using VBA?

Tags: ms-project

When I try to import ***both*** the Task Start date and the Task Finish date using the below code, the dates for the first task appear to import okay, but subsequent tasks' date values are changed from what they should be. If I comment out the line, `MapEdit Name:="Map ", DataCategory:=0, FieldName:="Finish", ExternalFieldName:="Task_Finish_Date"`, to only import the Start date, then the correct dates are imported for the Start dates for all tasks (the dates are not changed) but, of course, I don't get my Finish dates. How can I import ***both*** the Start and the Finish dates for all my tasks?

```
MapEdit Name:="Map ", Create:=True, OverwriteExisting:=True, DataCategory:=0, CategoryEnabled:=True, _
        TableName:=ws.Name, FieldName:="Name", ExternalFieldName:="Task_Name", ExportFilter:="All Tasks", ImportMethod:=0, _
        HeaderRow:=True, AssignmentData:=False, TextDelimiter:=Chr$(9), TextFileOrigin:=0, UseHtmlTemplate:=False, IncludeImage:=False
    MapEdit Name:="Map ", DataCategory:=0, FieldName:="Outline Level", ExternalFieldName:="Task_Outline_Level"
    MapEdit Name:="Map ", DataCategory:=0, FieldName:="Created", ExternalFieldName:="Task_Created_Date"
    MapEdit Name:="Map ", DataCategory:=0, FieldName:="Start", ExternalFieldName:="Task_Start_Date"
    MapEdit Name:="Map ", DataCategory:=0, FieldName:="Finish", ExternalFieldName:="Task_Finish_Date"
    MapEdit Name:="Map ", DataCategory:=0, FieldName:="% Complete", ExternalFieldName:="Task_Percent_Complete"
    MapEdit Name:="Map ", DataCategory:=0, FieldName:="Notes", ExternalFieldName:="Task_Notes"
    MapEdit Name:="Map ", DataCategory:=0, FieldName:="Board Status", ExternalFieldName:="Task_Board_Status"
    MapEdit Name:="Map ", DataCategory:=0, FieldName:="Resource Names", ExternalFieldName:="Project_Resources"
    MapEdit Name:="Map ", DataCategory:=0, FieldName:="Task Tags", ExternalFieldName:="Task_Tags"
    MapEdit Name:="Map ", DataCategory:=0, FieldName:="Task Mode", ExternalFieldName:="Task_Mode"
    
FileOpenEx Name:=xlFile2, ReadOnly:=False, Merge:=0, FormatID:="MSProject.ACE.14", map:="Map ", DoNotLoadFromEnterprise:=True
```

Comment: It's hard to say what is going on without seeing a sample of the actual data you are importing and the resulting schedule. Suggest testing without importing Outline Level and % Complete; for that matter, start with the minimum fields (task name, start, finish) and add fields that affect date calculations one at a time (e.g. OL, % complete, task mode).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like I was able to fix my problem with importing Task Start and Finish dates.

As I think [Rachel Hettinger](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1056632/rachel-hettinger) suspected, the problem was not with my VBA -- it was with the data that was passing from Excel to MS Project. I was using Power Query to pull the data into Excel from its source. Power Query “fills in” empty date type values with nulls. I was passing the data from Power Query to Excel as such date type values. This brought in null dates instead of empty dates. When I then imported the supposedly empty, but actually null, date values from Excel into MS Project, Project added new, and changed existing, dates throughout my tasks.

Now what I do, instead, is I change my date values in Power Query from date type values to text type values. Also in Power Query, I then convert each null date entry to “”. That way, when I pass the data from Power Query to Excel, the dates are passed as text type values and the empty dates are brought into Excel as actual empty dates. (I do *format* the date columns in Excel as dates though.) And, when I subsequently import those empty values from Excel into MS Project, project handles them correctly.